# PHP/JavaScript Design patterns for web based infosystems

Tags: php, javascript, html, oop, frameworks

I've been coding for years and have found myself in a point of frustration. I am working on a new web based service that also has a UI and it will be developed from ground up. It will use some open source components, but is mainly a new thing in its own right.

But here's my problem. Building such a system means building all of those components:

- PHP backend
- HTML views
- CSS styles
- JavaScript front-end
- AJAX asynchronous connections

I want all of them to follow the same 'pattern', in a way that a module in the system consists of a folder or set of files that incorporates all of those components within that module.

But I am having a tough time with getting the architecture so that I would like it. Here is what I have so far:

- The entire main system is more or less written in procedural PHP. This solves the request URL, deals with caching, logging and debugging and loads in other components.
- PHP, when building the page, loads in module specific javascript files, CSS files, HTML files and other components based on the current module. This means that every module is as lightweight as possible, while being able to be extended however much based on current modules needs.
- System also incorporates OOP components of objects (such as 'users' or other type of classes) that can be used system wide.
- The system is built with MVC principles, though without OOP.

But I do feel really -dirty- for having built the main system in a procedural way. I did start writing it in OOP at first, but quickly found myself in headaches due to having to get everything fit the same system. It was OOP, but it was tightly coupled, which I disliked for while it was written the OOP way, components were really not that independent or were just a hassle to manage.

Are there any patterns or guides I could follow to get a better result? What I like about the current system is that I can call in anything, pre-view-rendering PHP, or HTML views, CSS styling, additional Javascript functions and AJAX communication per-demand, keeping the footpring wonderfully small, but it feels dirty. I even use a global for main database connection (though it is a global object).

Any ideas? It would not be a problem at all if it were just one language, but trying to make everything work together is a bit of a headache.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you researched any of the thousands of PHP frameworks/CMS systems/etc? There are tons of examples of how this can be done out there.

Comment: Its very difficult to answer your question because you are not presenting any real problem. I am currently working on such a system almost like your one but off-course with some differences. I am using MVC/OOP. I can't imagine you are handling it procedurally. I think until your project have some boundaries there should not be any problem in OOP.

Comment: You could look at Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture, GoF patterns, etc and implement them yourself. However, the easiest,(and most obvious) answer is to look at how frameworks (which have already faced this _exact_ problem) have implemented these patterns and either (a) use the framework or (b) adapt the framework's approaches into your app. Look for open-source frameworks in your chosen paradigm, look through how they do things, and see what jibes with your app.

Comment: Could any of you give some examples of what frameworks I should take a look at? Because there are very many out there and many of them overly complicated and with a too big a footprint. Is there anything that is very lightweight that solves these problems already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://agiletoolkit.org/ implements exactly what you are looking for. It's source-code is available on http://github.com/atk4/atk4 so you can learn from there.

What I learned many things while [creating Agile Toolkit](http://agiletoolkit.org/about/authors).

- Look at desktop systems. - Cocoa, Objective Windows and other object-oriented desktop systems have solved those problems long time ago. Create views, connect actions, define call-backs. This maps into HTML-templated views, JavaScript bindings and AJAX requests.
- Runtime Object Tree. In Agile Toolkit, the first phase is initialization. During this phase objects are inserted into each-other. For instance you add Button into Form and add Form into Page. Then there is rendering phase which recursively produces HTML from everything. This makes much more sense that having components echo HTML.
- jQuery UI widgets. Using those was a great way to solve many problems. Views in Agile Tolokit can talk with respective jQuery UI Widgets.
- Objects you have mentioned are "Models" in Agile Toolkit. If you are looking for stand-alone version, you can rely on some ORM framework. I've made my own to have it tighter integrated with the Views.
- Reconsider de-coupling. If you are developing all the system by yourself then coupling gives you lots of benefits. Especially if it's object-oriented architecture and you inherit things. You would need some Java experience or Desktop development experience to get this thing right.

Links:

- [What is Object Oriented Web Development](http://agiletoolkit.org/learn/intro)
- [Object Oriented Programming in PHP](http://agiletoolkit.org/blog/how-to-use-object-oriented-programming-in-php/)
- [Execution steps in Agile Toolkit](http://agiletoolkit.org/learn/understand/api/exec)

Comment: It is not exactly what I am looking for, but it is certainly closer to what I have in mind in comparison to bloated frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

**Without knowing anything else, my thoughts:**

- **If you didn't like your OOP code, you probably designed it wrong.**  The idea with object orientation is that objects represent things quite naturally and as such they should be quite painless to deal with.  If it's the coupling that you don't like, there are techniques to fix that.
- **It sounds like your MVC pattern is wrong.**  The HTML/CSS/JavaScript stuff should all be handled in the View aspect.  It seems to me that you have used some MVC principles while disregarding others.  Of course, without your code this can only be a suspicion.

Comment: Well, it depends. MVC, in the most classic sense, is different from how people usually implement it. Javascript and browser are a controller, not a view. But that aside, my main problem was that I had this huge single class for the main engine, which was kind-of pointless, since everything depended on it. I've always felt that if there is a single instance of a class (and there can never be more than one), it should not be a class in the first place.

Comment: I agree on the JavaScript part: it can be controller stuff.  And if you can only have one instance of a class (and there can never be more than one), that doesn't mean you shouldn't make a class.  However, it sounds like you tried to God-class it.  Don't do that.

Comment: But what could you recommend me to look at? Because I want a system that has main components (like main CSS file, main functions library for PHP and JavaScript/AJAX as well as CSS file, functions libraries and JavaScript/AJAX per module on-demand). I want as low footprint as possible, while every module can work independently. Now I agree that the modules should be extended classes of the main class, but how to build an architecture for that to work? Where would the solving be if not in a God class? I just need some guidance here, since I don't want to compromise :)

Comment: @Kristovaher, I'm not sure exactly what you are asking.  Could you update your question with the inheritance scheme you currently have?  That would be a big help for everyone.